# Error running Oracle DB function on linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I'm trying to get data from a function I've written in an Oracle database to a linked SQL Server database.

For Oracle, my function is:

```
SELECT * FROM table(STD_DBA.FN_GET_PRODLOSS(1));
```

Basically, my function takes the number of days I pass to it (1 in this case), subtracts that number of days from today's date, and gives me the table entries for all the intervening days. In Oracle, this works great, no errors. I can also get it to run using SQL*Plus on my linked server with no problem. My question is how to get it to run on my linked SQL Server using an SQL statement.

From my research, it seems like `OPENQUERY` would be the way to go. I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([myOracleDB], 'SELECT * FROM table(STD_DBA.FN_GET_PRODLOSS(1))')
```

but I keep getting this error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "myOracleDB" returned message "ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-02063: preceding line from RTRSHIST

Can anyone help me with how to make this work?

Comment: Your function seems to be written so that it is nls sensitive. Go through it and make sure you are using explicit date formats everywhere you need to be.

Comment: [duplicate on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281197/error-running-oracle-db-function-on-linked-sql-server)